# How to define a constant when running script/server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

I want to start up my Rails development server like this:

```
script/server OFFLINE_MODE=1
```

and have a method in `application_controller.rb` that checks for the presence of that constant:

```
helper_method :offline_mode?
def offline_mode?
  defined?(OFFLINE_MODE) ? true : false
end
```

so I can hide stuff in my app when I'm coding without access to the internet. For some reason though, OFFLINE_MODE doesn't ever seem to be defined and the method always returns false.. thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`script/server offline foo bar`

Your helpers

```
helper_method :offline_mode?, :foo?
def offline_mode?
  ARGV.include?('offline')
end

# another example
def foo?
  ARGV.include?('foo')
end
```

Comment: Sweet! That didn't quite work but led me down the right path: http://zeke.tumblr.com/post/501363554/rails-on-a-plane

Comment: @Zeke, yea I had a mistake at first. I fixed my code example :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an environment variable to do this:

```
OFFLINE_MODE=1 script/server

def offline_mode?
    defined?(ENV['OFFLINE_MODE']) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: The obvious advantage is that you can `export OFFLINE_MODE=1` once for your session, then all commands will have that environment var set.